# Clojure: Template with Enlive

Tags: clojure, enlive

I copied a very basic sample from https://github.com/cgrand/enlive, but it doesn't compile:

```
(ns web.handler
  (:require
    [compojure.core :refer :all]
    [compojure.handler]
    [compojure.route :as route]
    [net.cgrand.enlive-html :as html]))

;; Compiler throws in the next line, see the message below.
(html/deftemplate main-template "templates/index.html"
  []
  [:head :title] (html/content "Enlive starter kit"))

(defroutes app-routes
  (GET "/" [] "Hello")
  (GET "/ping/:what" [what] (str "<h1>Ping '" what "'</h1>"))
  (route/resources "/")
  (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (compojure.handler/site app-routes))
```

Error I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException, compiling:(handler.clj:9:1)
```

I run with command:

```
lein ring server-headless
```

How to make it work?

**EDIT**

My investigation so far: error throw from `enlive-html.clj:54`:

```
(defn tagsoup-parser 
 "Loads and parse an HTML resource and closes the stream."
 [stream]
  (filter map?
    (with-open [^java.io.Closeable stream stream]
      (xml/parse (org.xml.sax.InputSource. stream) startparse-tagsoup)))) ; #54
```

Probably `org.xml.sax` is not referenced? How can I do this with `lein`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error normally happens when the template file is not found. With `templates/index.html`, it is looking in the `resources/templates` directory or in the `src/templates` directory.

Comment: Was just is `templates`, moved to `src/tampletes`, works fine! `resources/templates` works as well. Thank you!

Comment: As I briefly browsed the code, it sinks to `ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream`. I'm not familiar with Java infrastructure, but this is where `resources/` and `src/` paths come from?

Comment: When you specify a string path, Enlive uses the built in java resource methods. This searches the current classLoader's classpath, which is setup by Leiningen using your project config, and the default config. If you need other paths, you can add them to your project.clj, or you can open it yourself and pass deftemplate an InputStream.